# Paste to excel from other application

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have a macro which is trying to copy data from PDF file into Excel. I have a problem with pasting method - my code is debugging in the last row "wkSheet.Paste" with message "paste method of worksheet class failed".
The strange for me is that I can paste it by pressing F8, but it do not want to paste automatically.
I have tried to activate excel file at first, I was trying with the pause break, I was trying to select column instead of a cell or range and I was trying to other pasting methods like "pastespecial xlpastevalues".
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
Private Sub copyFromPDF()

Dim mainFile As Workbook
Set mainFile = ThisWorkbook
Dim myPath As String
myPath = mainFile.Path & "\"

Dim o As Variant
    Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
o = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe " & myPath & "test.pdf", vbNormalFocus)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))
SendKeys ("^a")
SendKeys ("^c")
SendKeys "%{F4}"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
appWord.Visible = False
appWord.Documents.Add.Content.Paste

With appWord
    .Selection.WholeStory
    .Selection.Copy
    .ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    .Quit
End With

Set wkSheet = ActiveSheet
wkSheet.Range("A1").Select
wkSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. The thing is that this is not a problem with pasting to the Word application which is invisible, but into the Excel application (wkSheet.Paste)

Comment: With `wkSheet.Paste Destination:=wkSheet.Range("A1")` you could skip the Select